# Google Chrome missing Flash / Shockwave for Jing videos?

Tags: google-chrome, flash, google-chrome-extensions, embedded

I was trying to watch a screencast using Google Chrome on this page:

> http://www.firebreath.org/display/documentation/Mac+Video+Tutorial

However, i'm just getting "Missing Plugin"

[image]

I have the latest version of Chrome installed:

[image]

How can I get this to work in Chrome?

**Update**

I forgot to mention I visited the "Install Flash Player" page. The results:

[image]

Hmm, also seems not to be working in Safari. Firefox works.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling Flash and/or Shockwave?

Comment: it says it's up to date too. updating the question.

Comment: I'd still try uninstalling then reinstalling. Just in case something got corrupted.

Comment: Are you using chrome on PC or Mac? Does the page work for you? I don't know if I can install flash separate from Chrome, maybe I will try reinstall Chrome.

Comment: Interesting - I'm on PC and I get "Missing Plug-in" too. I wonder if there's an issue with the latest version of Chrome.

Comment: Maybe it's something to do with that page. It is not working in Safari either, but it is with Firefox.

Comment: It's not working for me either (Chrome Dev on OS X). So I guess this has to do with this page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this was due to a confluence bug where it used the wrong mimetype.  Details can be found here:

https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/CONF-23268?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:changehistory-tabpanel